# How can I locate TinyMCE plugins in a separate directory?

Tags: javascript, tinymce

For the most part, I use the default TinyMCE plugins.

Every now and then, I make my own for my own specific needs.

To do so, I go to the tinymce directory, then the plugin directory, and then one of the individual plugin directories, and modify the script as necessary.

All is good except my memory (not my computer's but my head's).  4 months goes by, and I decide to upgrade to a newer version or something.  Which ones did I change?  I have no idea!

I would like to create my own directory called myTinyMCE_Plugins, and not even include it in the tinymce directory.  That way I just need to remember to move my specific plugins over.

But when configuring TinyMCE, I can add the plugin name, but don't seem to be able to specify the plugin's path.  Yes, I can use symbolic links, but this too is not ideal.

How can I locate TinyMCE plugins in a separate directory?

```
tinymce.init({
    plugins: ["someDefaultPlugin someCustomPlugin"],
    toolbar: "someDefaultPlugin | someCustomPlugin"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

After asking the question, I found http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Tutorials:Creating_a_plugin.

```
You can also have the plugin in any location you want by loading the plugin.js/plugin.min.js files directrly after the tinymce.js/tinymce.min.js.
Example of loading the plugin from another url

<script src="/tinymce/js/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script src="/scripts/my.tinymce.plugin.js"></script>
<script>
tinymce.init({..});
</script>
```

Comment: After further investigation, I believe this is not the best approach.  I will post new findings should they arrive.